# Hibernate proxy error occurred launch job in Spring Batch

Tags: hibernate, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

Hello I got hibernate error in Spring batch application

```
ERROR: org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob - Encountered fatal error executing job
org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException: Attempt to update job execution id=33 with wrong version (0), where current version is 1
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.updateJobExecution(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:210)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update(SimpleJobRepository.java:155)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy54.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.updateStatus(AbstractJob.java:383)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:276)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

According to the error log, I faced proxy error at Abstract Job Class (which provided by Spring Batch) 

I guess that since Abstract Job Class do not have any non-parameter Constructor, CGLIB cannot provide any proxy class..

How can I solve this problem?


I'm using spring batch admin now

Answer (score 0):

that exception

```
org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException: Attempt to update job execution id=33 with wrong version (0), where current version is 1
```

means that for some reason your step transaction locking has failed.

Might be caused your business logic transaction being set as RollbackOnly mode which would cause spring tables to be inconsistent state as well => optimistic locking occurs.

Try to add logging for hibernate and showing of the actual sql. This might help you to figure out where the problem actually is.